# Why does UITableView lock up when switching focus from UITextField to UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableViewController that is used to present a series of questions via custom UITableViewCells. Each UITableViewCell has a UITextField for data input and a UITextView for adding any necessary notes relevant to that question. When the UITextField calls textFieldDidEndEditing it performs some calculations and then reloads the tableView data. Everything works great, except for instances when the user switches focus from the UITextField to the UITextField. In those instances, the app locks up for a few seconds and the CPU goes to 100%. Here is the relevant code:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    //println("Reloading table")
    self.answer = textField.text
    self.updateCalculations()
    self.tableView?.reloadData()
}
```

This only happens when moving from the UITextField to the UITextView. Moving to another UITextField does not cause any issues, and moving from UITextView to UITextField also does not cause any issues.

If I move all of this to textFieldShouldEndEditing the lockup stops, but the reloadData doesn't seem to fire. I thought it might be the calculation function I was using, but if I take that out, the problem still occurs. As far as I can tell, there is some kind of hangup that happens when calling reloadData form DidEndEditing while switching to a UITextView.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try to dispatch the reloadData to the main queue like this: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in self.tableView?.reloadData() })

Comment: performing the reloadData on the main thread in textFieldShouldEndEditing does properly perform the reload, but it has the unfortunate side effect of causing the same app lockup as when used in the textFieldDidEndEditing function. So far it seems that calling tableView.reloadData() is probably not a good thing to do while the keyboard is up. Makes me wonder if there is a more appropriate point to call the reloadData() to update the other cells.